# Do light versions of linux compromise security?

Tags: linux, security, internet-security, puppylinux

I was planning to install some light version of linux (e.g. SliTaz or Puppy) in an old 512 Mb RAM Thinkpad.

My question is if the use of any of these light versions, as compared to standard Ubuntu, involve a lowering of security and/or privacy.

I was concerned in particular about the safety in the use of e-mail (either institutional or non-institutional), or login into web accounts.

Comment: I would assume that they are more secure because less programs are installed, which might have security vulnerabilities. But it is more a feeling than deep knowledge.

Comment: It depends on what you're actually using on those instances. Potentially they could have less attack surface in a default installation. On the other hand, if they're smaller distros, it might take them longer to implement patches. Describing your actual requirements might get you some better answers.

Comment: Besides what appears in the last paragraph of my question, I can add that I would use it inside an institutional network, with wired connection.